# How can I share my computer screen on a LAN?

Tags: remote-desktop, lan, remote-access, screen-sharing

I want to share my computer screen over LAN, without an internet connection. How can I do it?

There is different software like:

- LogMeIn
- Team Viewer
- etc.

But these require an internet connection.

Answer (score 9):

- [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vnc)
- [Windows Remote Desktop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services)
- [Apple Remote desktop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Remote_Desktop)

Should sort you out.

Comment: It's really sad when the dodgy web-based systems have more mindshare than the built-in system services.

Comment: Agreed!
Lucky he didn't mention Copilot...

Comment: I'd probably add nx/nomachine to the list - google's working on a server, and there's freenx and its probably the fastest, best performing remote access method i've seen.

Answer (score 2):

You can use TeamViewer on LAN. [This is how to do it](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/40-Can-TeamViewer-be-used-within-a-local-network-LAN-only.aspx):

> You can establish Remote control sessions on your local network
>   directly by using IP addresses or computer names. By default this
>   feature is deactivated because software firewalls may open an
>   acceptance dialog when configured this way.
>
> To activate the LAN mode in TeamViewer full version and Host module:
>
> - In the menu click on Extras and then on Options
> - On the General tab activate Accept incoming LAN connections

Comment: Your answer isn't really different from the one posted by Sunes.

Answer (score 1):

No Internet connection is needed to share a desktop over a LAN, supposing both computers are in the same LAN. You did not specify which operating system you are using (some provide their own desktop sharing).

As an alternative you could use [vnc](http://www.realvnc.com/)

Comment: Whenever somebody say vnc I like to add VNC SC (single click), That means that VNC has server which Can be activated by distributing only one file without installing and preconfigured as You need

Answer (score 1):

Use [TeamViewer LAN](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx).

1. Use network connections to find the ip address of your PC.
2. Use this IP address on TeamViewer on any other pc in the same LAN.

U will be able to use what you want.